# Unable to resize ext4 file system in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: partitioning, 18.04, resize

Not able to swapoff the Ext4 filesystem through GParted.

[image: Gparted]

Comment: Boot from a live cd and turn swap off. Then you will be able to delete/resize that space.

Comment: Can you help me to Boot from a live cd and turn swap off ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Download ubuntu image [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/xenial/ubuntu-16.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso).
2. Burn on USB ([Windows](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0)/[Ubuntu](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0)).
3. Boot from USB.
4. Open a terminal:

   Execute as root

   ```
   swapoff -a
   ```

   To make the changes permanent edit /etc/fstab and comment out the swap entry.

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/fstab
   ```

   [image: disable swap entry]
5. Reboot.

Comment: And if this is a server with out this option?